# Magento 2 Daily Back Size

Tags: magento2, backup

I have magento 2 setup to generate backup on daily basis, code and db only and we keep the backup for 7 days. I have noticed that backup size has been increasing and right now about ~25G/ day backup.

any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

here is what it did last night:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 26G Aug 19 13:43 1534702909_nomedia.tgz
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 24G Aug 19 13:43 1534702979_nomedia.tgz
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 36G Aug 19 13:10 ~tmp-1534703275.7177.tar
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 36G Aug 19 13:10 ~tmp-1534703420.3653.tar
```

four files were created last night check the size of files.... any suggestions please?

Sajid.

Comment: is that previous  backup file including in new one?

Comment: seems like it, my configuration is to backup without media, and the part confusing me is that it is creating temp files of 35G+ each and not removing it